# When is it necessary to add class for semantics?

Tags: html, css

I want to write semantic beautiful no-nonsense HTML. When is the right time to include class and when it's not? Should I add class on every element of my HTML?

To write semantic markup, we must use HTML tags correctly so that our markup is both human-readable and machine-readable. When we write semantic markup we can no longer select HTML elements based on visual presentation. Instead, we select HTML elements based on their semantic meaning, and then use CSS to define the visual presentation of our content. When writing semantic markup, the presentation of web page elements is kept completely separate and distinct from the markup of the content itself.

```
<body> 

<ul class="post">
<li class="title"> <h3>Title of Post</h3> </li>
<li class="content"><p> Lorem Ipsum bla bla..</p></li>
<li class="hashtag"><a href="site.come/hash/samplepost">#samplepost </a> 
</li>
</ul>

</body>

<style> 
.title{code}
.content{code}
.hashtag{code}
</style>
```

or

```
<body>

<ul class="post">
<li> <h3>Title of Post</h3> </li>
<li><p>Ipsum bla bla..</p></li>
<li><a href="site.come/hash/samplepost">#samplepost </a></li>
</ul>

</body>

<style> 
.post > li > h3{code}
.post > li > p {code}
.post > li > a {code}
</style>
```

Which of these is more semantic? Should we use class on everything or only when necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Only use classes when you want to style a group of elements in a similar way (and ids for unique elements), it can be confusing for someone picking up your code if class names don't have any styles attached to them, and it just adds clutter.

Using semantic tags will make your html more semantic - ie. header, nav, main, footer, aside - etc. Some of these tags even make it easier for screen readers to navigate. w3 schools has good info about semantic tags: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Comment: of course. The question is whether I should apply the class to a div and call the nested tag within the classes with CSS or give the nested tags a name individually.

Comment: Oh I see. I would probably lean more towards just having a class on the div, to keep things simple. Can always refactor later if you need to give the children elements their own classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to be attached to HTML tags, who knows where else you will have to use a similar interface. It’s best to stick with some CSS methodology ([for example BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/)) and write styles based on CSS classes. From the presence of classes, the layout will not be less semantic. The main html tags to write correctly.
In general, if you want to avoid problems in the future, use the css classes.
I would write like this:

```html
<body>
  <div class="posts-list">
    <h3 class="posts-list__title">Title of Post</h3>
    <ul class="post-list__ul">
      <li class="post-list__item">
        <p> Lorem Ipsum bla bla..</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="posts-list__hashtag">
      <a href="site.come/hash/samplepost">#samplepost</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If i want similar interface but different style, I can just make a new class. eg: .post1 .post2 .post3 to avoid conflicts. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Creating classes everywhere is a lot of work and can potentially cause some problems later on. If you add a class to every HTML tag, imagine how hard to maintain the code is going to be if the project becomes bigger. As mentioned above there are specific methodologies which can be really helpful, and BEM is a popular, but **not the only one**, you can use other. If you don't want to use methodology and stick with simple classes for now (though at some point I really suggest diving into that topic, you don't have to know perfectly how to use specific methodology, but how they works, if you ever join any team working with code, then they are going to tell you what methodology they picked for the project), I suggest using second code, but with comments:

```html
<body>

  <!-- Post -->
  <ul class="post">
    <!-- Title -->
    <li>
      <h3>Title of Post</h3>
    </li>
    <!-- Content -->
    <li>
      <p>Ipsum bla bla..</p>
    </li>
    <!-- Hashtag -->
    <li><a href="site.come/hash/samplepost">#samplepost </a></li>
  </ul>

</body>

<style>
  .post>li>h3 {
    code
  }
  
  .post>li>p {
    code
  }
  
  .post>li>a {
    code
  }
</style>
```

Comments are really simple and powerful tool. They will help you getting oriented in the project really quick, and avoid adding unnecessary classes for semantics.

Comment: the work part is not a problem since  I have a static builder on my project. This question only focuses on the end result of the readable HTML.

Comment: This, as well as all other responses imply, that it makes no real sense to add classes just because you can. You want to "write semantic beautiful no-nonsense HTML". What is the sense to add a class to a tag, which is prolly never (class of the tag) going to be used? It's like adding an empty <p> tag every couple of lines. I understand that, adding a class to a HTML tag like in your example, gives you information about that tag, but if you are not using (or not going to use) this class for any other purpose, then use comments instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is your content is not a list, so you shouldn't be using `ul/li`. That bad semantics, and as such worse than no semantics at all.

Your semantic markup is this:

```
<body> 
  <h3>Title of Post</h3>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum bla bla..</p>
  <a href="site.come/hash/samplepost">#samplepost</a> 
</body>
```

If you want to create a containing block for your post, to might reasonably wrap it in a `div` element, and although it's not necessary for such simple content, you could also consider wrapping it in a `main` element. You could put your anchor inside a `p` element but that makes no semantic difference.

Now you add one or more classes to any element when it is *sensible* to do so. What is sensible? It means not going over the top, forcing a class onto an element just because it looks naked without one. Generally, a good rule of thumb is to add a class when there's a utilitarian purpose in doing so. Classes are a way of putting you content in to categories, so that categorisation should be useful in some way.

For example, it might be that you want to style all the content with a particular category a similar way. Or it might be that you want to add some common functionality via JavaScript to all the content in a particular category.

Or it might be that you want to identify a category of content for your maintenance purposes. For example, suppose you have a large document describing products that you sell. With each product is a price. Even if you have no intention of styling the price differently from the other content, nor have any relevant JavaScript, you might add a class of "price" to each one, so that when the time comes to update your prices, you can easily find them all in your editor, and thus make sure that you don't miss one.

For each utilitarian purpose, think about opportunities, rather than necessities. By adding a class to categorise some some content, you are creating an opportunity for common styling, or functionality, or discovery to be applied.